# I'm getting an error with link_to_route in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, hyperlink

I got a table and the las column (actions) is supposed to have links to edit and delete a record. By watching some tutorials I saw an example where they use this links with Laravel Collective like this:

```
    {!!link_to_route('view-folder.edit', $title = 'Edit', 
                $parameters = $country->id, $attributes = ['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])!!}
```

But I'm getting the error

```
ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 278:
Route [countries.editCountry] not defined. 
(View: /var/www/laravel/example/resources/views/countries/listCountries.blade.php)
```

How should I use this laravel collective links?

Answer (score 2):

Did you define a route with the name 'view-folder.edit' in routes.php?  Judging by the error, that route doesn't exist.  It should look something like the following:

```
Route::get('edit/{country}', ['as' => 'view-folder.edit', 'uses' => 'CountryController@edit']);
```

Comment: Actually I had a route to that view in my routes file, only that with a different syntax. I just use your's and it's working now, but my next question would be: Why this route didn't work?

Route::get('countries/edit', 'CountriesController@edit');

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is because your link_to_route() method uses 'view-folder.edit' as the name, however your route was not given any name. As you'll see in my route, I used 'view-folder.edit' for the 'as' property. These are called named routes. This allows you to change the path of your route and not have it effect the references/links to that route. Please mark the above as correct if it helped! :)

Comment: @PabloQ just wanted to check that this answer helped you, and if so, make sure you mark it correct so others can know when searching for this question!